# Information about the Translation Engines

Tags: api, machine-learning, nlp

I am interested in statistical machine translation. Can anyone suggest where can I find more information about state-of-the-art implementations like Google Translate, Microsoft Translate?

I would like to know about the following stuff:

1) **The size of training data for different languages.**

2) **The quality of the translations for different languages.**

and any other interesting point about engine implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have more details about the state of the art, you should have a look on this book: http://www.statmt.org/book/
It is probably a little outdated but it interesting.

The famous tool in MT is Moses: http://statmt.org/moses/
You'll find an overview of this tool, and you can try a tutorial if you're brave.

With these documentation you'll have a more detailed comprehension of the task.